# Unbale to resolve com.avaje.ebean.Model

Tags: java, playframework-2.6

I am new in Playframework using Java.

As per PlayFramework documentation i have added addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.2") to plugin.sbt and added lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean) in build.sbt. Still i am getting error on com.avaje.ebean. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Change it to `import io.ebean.*;`

Answer (score 0):

If you did this while sbt is running, you need to use the `reload` command for the changes to be recognised.